# Positioning UserControl relative to Form or Screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, location

Is there any way to get and set the `.Location` of an `UserControl`, which is positioned on a `Container` (e.g. a `Panel`) relative to the "most-parental" Form?

I know that there is the possibility of calculating the offset of the `Panel` itself and adding it to the `.Location` of the `UserControl`.

But in my case the number of parent-levels is unknown and can differ from case to case.
So once the `UserControl` could be placed on a `Panel` which is directly on the `Form`. But there is also the possibility that the `UserControl` is placed on a 2nd `Panel` which is on the 1st `Panel` which is on the `Form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim pnt As Point

pnt = UserControl.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
pnt = Me.PointToClient(pnt)
```

This calculates the location relative to your *Form*. Change *Me* to any control, if you like

Now, if you want to *set* the location eg (100, 100), relative to your *Form*

```
pnt = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(100, 100))
pnt = UserControl.Parent.PointToClient(pnt)
UserControl.Location = pnt
```

Remember that, if the new location is outside the parent area the control will not be visible.

Comment: Do you know which solution is the better one regarding the performance, yours or Capellan's?

Comment: @mookey If you call both a few times no difference noticible. But if you call them many times a second maybe mine because i am using native functions. You have to test it though to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

What if you take your idea of calculating the offset of the Panel and calculate the offset recursively back to the Form?  i.e. I have a Textbox1 within a Panel2 within a Panel1.  Panel1 is located at .Left 266, Panel2 is at .Left 77 within Panel1.

```
Private Function GetLeftOffset(ByVal UserControl As Control) As Int32
    Dim intLeftOffset As Int32 = 0
    If Not TypeOf UserControl.Parent Is Form Then
        intLeftOffset = UserControl.Parent.Left
        intLeftOffset += GetLeftOffset(UserControl.Parent)
    End If
    Return intLeftOffset
End Function
```

Now if I GetLeftOffset(Me.TextBox1), it returns an Offset of 343 (266 + 77).

Comment: I found this the most useful. Also note the padding for the parent(s).

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to place a context menu near a control like a textbox or button.  You can set x and y to zero to return the location of a control itself.

```
'--- Return the screen location of a control with an offset

Private Function Offset(ByRef controlObj As Control, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Point

  Dim pt As Point
  Dim parentObj As Control = controlObj.Parent

  Do While parentObj IsNot controlObj.FindForm
    x += parentObj.Location.X
    y += parentObj.Location.Y
    parentObj = parentObj.Parent
  Loop

  pt = PointToScreen(controlObj.Location)
  pt.Offset(x, y)
  Return pt

End Function
```